# HttpClient get response from time to time

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, httpclient, httpresponse

I use HttpClient to receive data from my API. API returns data all time, but the client (UWP) get the answer from the server from time to time. Based on my test, I suppose, that it depends on the size of the answer (model contains 4 fields: 1 guid & 4 string fields), and error I catch with 73 records in return list.

Here is my API method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetClassList()
    {
        ...
            IEnumerable<Class> classList = await _profileService.GetClasses();

            IEnumerable<ClassViewModel> vm = classList.Select(e => new ClassViewModel(e));

            var response =  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, vm );
            return response;

        ...
    }
```

UWP code, that calls the API:

```
try
{
   using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string str = "http://address/api/v2/GetClassList";
        HttpResponseMessage answer = await client.GetAsync(str);
        string response = await answer.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
    }
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
 }
```

Default timeout for HttpClient = 01:40, catched exception after 5 min:

> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
>   Message = "The operation was canceled.

StackTrace:

```
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Could it depend on async calls? How to handle it? What wrong I do? 
I'll be glad to hear any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you query your server with a different client, say Postman? Also, the stack trace suggest that the answer of the server contains a non 2XX status code. What status code does it exactly return? For me, it seems likely that there is some kind of error on the server-side and it is not responding correctly.

Comment: I have used AdvancedRest client, everything is ok. Also, I have tried to get the response from the API from blank console app and again it works fine too.

Comment: was there no inner exception or more detailed message in that?

Comment: As a side note, you could simplify code by using `string response = await client.GetStringAsync(str);`

Comment: So it's basically a simple RESTfull api call? or is it some kinda service bus?

Comment: There are no inner exceptions; 
Yes, it's simple RESTful;
`string response = await client.GetStringAsync(str);` - no changes, still  exception, thx

Comment: Please try to enable the `InternetClientServer ` and `privateNetworkClientServer ` capabilities.

Comment: useless for this issue. But thx for the try